# How to use Netty deflator to compress the response sent to Browser

Tags: java, gzip, netty

I am trying to use compressor available in netty, added the following line in channel pipeline

```
pipeline.addLast("gzip", new HttpContentCompressor());
```

I am setting the response header `"Content-Encoding"` to `"gzip"`.

My question here is how to set the content, I tried the following

```
response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(responseText, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

where `responseText` --> String that I want to send to browser.

I get an error that the content is not gzip stream

> org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.embedder.CodecEmbedderException:
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.compression.CompressionException:
>   decompression failure (-3): not a gzip stream

Should I gzip the `responseText` and then do a `setContent(gzippedResponse)`? or am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 5):

- You don't need to set the response header "Content-Encoding" to "gzip". Netty does it for you.  See `HttpContentEncoder` from which `HttpContentCompressor` is inherited.
- You don't need to gzip `responseText`.
- Your pipeline should look something like this:

  ```
  // Create a default pipeline implementation.
  ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();

  // Decodes ChannelBuffer into HTTP Request message
  pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());

  // Encodes HTTTPRequest message to ChannelBuffer
  pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());

  // Compress
  pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor(1));

  // Handler to dispatch processing to our services
  pipeline.addLast("handler", new YourHttpRequestHandler());
  ```

Comment: Thanks @Veebs. That got the stuff working, the reason for the exception was I did not pass following header in the request  `request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.Values.GZIP);`